# Android Linkify without any action

Tags: android

Is there any way to be able to create a hyperlink for a pattern but when it is clicked nothing should happen, only the pattern should be highlighted but no action should take place. I need this because my app needs to be able to identify some patterns so that a user can select them easily and be able to copy and paste them in other edit boxes. I tried using :

```
Linkify.addLinks(text, pattern, scheme);
```

where `scheme = null`,

but the app crashes with the error

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6903): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=6878 (has extras) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all scheme must be valid URL as already said and have default activity to handle scheme. Your problem is that your intent could not catch by any Activity so you have to provide an Activity for that purpose and your scheme is null so its probably will be your next problem to handle.

I am pretty sure that you have much more pleasent solution for highlighting some pattern and copying it, if you have to do in this way you can call default activity when link clicked but with transparent background. Its not good solution but may handle what you want.

```
<activity android:name=".your.activity.declaration" ... android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Provide [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) inside this activity with scheme you provided.
Again this is not a good solution. May be you should change widgets you are using and take a look at [Clipboard Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html)

Comment: Thank you Burak Dede. Can you give me an example of how I can provide an intent filter.

Comment: Hi Burak Dede. Thank you very much for your answer, I was able to get this working by setting up a transparent activity. The problem now is I have to hit the "back" button to come back to my original activity that has the hyperlinks and it is quite distracting. Is it possible to invoke the copy/paste menu when the hyperlink is created while staying on the same activity?

Answer (score 0):

Refering to [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html), scheme should contain a valid URL. For your purpose try this

> TextView txtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
>
> txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml(("<\b>"+ StackOverFlow +"</b>"));

remove "\" before b.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please elaborate a little more on how to use your example. Should I use the above txtview as "text" in my code snippet - Linkify.addLinks(text, pattern, scheme);   What do I use for scheme?

Comment: @user887304, Dont use Linkify at all. Just replace your TextView with my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show those links, set `android:linksClickable` to false on the `TextView`.